# A shorter way to indicate “living in luxury”

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

> I hate......... I exercise moderation…It will be easy to forget your vision and purpose one you have fine clothes, fast horses and beautiful women. [In which case], you will be no better than a slave, and you will surely lose everything. [Genghis Khan.]

a) luxury 
b) luxurious life 
c) luxurious lifestyle

I was wondering which choice conveys the message of “living in luxury” best in my provided context.

Comment: Why didn't you include **d) living in luxury** as one of your alternatives, if that's the message you want to convey? And more specifically, since you obviously know that form of words already, ***why is that one not suitable**?* If it's important it should be a single word, and you have some objection to plain *I hate **luxury***, you might consider ***opulence***.

Comment: *extravagance* might work, especially if you contract it with *moderation*.

Comment: The word [sybaritism](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sybaritism) means exactly what you want, although it is a somewhat obscure word that even a lot of native speakers would have to look up.

Comment: Although it seems to be clear to me, but just for clearing up this ambiguity, because I am seeking an alternative to “living in luxury” which is obviously a routine way of conveying the message in my question @FumbleFingers.

Comment: What’s wrong with my provided options @Canadian Yankee?

Comment: The difference is that sybaritism includes the connotation of moral weakness or failure, which is what your quote seems to be about.